# react-bootstrap not getting Form tag after component import

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am very much new to react,As a start up i am trying to create login form using react-bootstrap but when i run the code it shows the errors in console as below

> index.js:40724 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Form' of
>   undefined
>       at App.render (index.js:40724)
>       at index.js:36958
>       at measureLifeCyclePerf (index.js:36238)
>       at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._renderValidatedComponentWithoutOwnerOrContext
>   (index.js:36957)
>       at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._renderValidatedComponent (index.js:36984)
>       at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.performInitialMount (index.js:36524)
>       at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (index.js:36420)
>       at Object.mountComponent (index.js:5996)
>       at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.performInitialMount (index.js:36533)
>       at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (index.js:36420)

Below is my code 
App.js file  - This file contains my login form,

```
  import React from 'react';
    import Bootstrap from "react-bootstrap";
     export class App extends React.Component{
        render(){
             return (
                     <Bootstrap.Form horizontal>
                  <Bootstrap.FormGroup controlId="formHorizontalEmail">
                    <Bootstrap.Col componentClass={LoginForm.ControlLabel} sm={2}>
                      Email
                    </Bootstrap.Col>
                    <Bootstrap.Col sm={10}>
                      <Bootstrap.FormControl type="email" placeholder="Email" />
                    </Bootstrap.Col>
                  </Bootstrap.FormGroup>

                  <Bootstrap.FormGroup controlId="formHorizontalPassword">
                    <Bootstrap.Col componentClass={LoginForm.ControlLabel} sm={2}>
                      Password
                    </Bootstrap.Col>
                    <Bootstrap.Col sm={10}>
                      <Bootstrap.FormControl type="password" placeholder="Password" />
                    </Bootstrap.Col>
                  </Bootstrap.FormGroup>

                  <Bootstrap.FormGroup>
                    <Bootstrap.Col  smOffset={2} sm={10}>
                      <Bootstrap.Checkbox>Remember me</Bootstrap.Checkbox>
                    </Bootstrap.Col>
                  </Bootstrap.FormGroup>

                  <Bootstrap.FormGroup>
                    <Bootstrap.Col smOffset={2} sm={10}>
                      <Bootstrap.Button type="submit">Sign in</Bootstrap.Button>
                    </Bootstrap.Col>
                  </Bootstrap.FormGroup>
                </Bootstrap.Form>
         );
        }
    }
```

File main.js - This file is a entry point of my application ,

```
import React from 'react';
    import  ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
    import {App} from './app.js';

    ReactDOM.render(<App />,document.getElementById('app'));
```

File Index.html - this file contains the html page

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>React First App</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="app">
</div>

<script  src="index.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

File Package.json

```
    {
  "name": "demo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "mode": "development",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --hot",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.32.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
    "webpack": "^3.5.5",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.7.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^0.28.11"
  }
}
```

File Webpack.config.js

```
var config = {

   entry: './main.js', // entry point
   output: {
         filename: 'index.js', // place where bundled app will be served
      },
   devServer: {
         inline: true, // autorefresh
         port: 8080 // development port server
      },
   module: {
         loaders: [
                        {
                           test: /\.jsx?$/, // search for js files 
                           exclude: /node_modules/,
                           loader: 'babel-loader',
                    query: {
                           presets: ['es2015', 'react'] // use es2015 and react
                        }
                     },
                {
                test: /\.css?$/, // search for css files 
                loader:'css-loader' 
                }
          ]


   }
}
module.exports = config;
```

I tried to use direct form but it's not working. if i use normal html tag then it's work. I though that it was a export issue  of component but its getting exported in main.js. Point to note that if I remove export from class and add `export default App` at the end of app.js then code does not export the component.This is strange but it's happening. it works with `export class component name` only

I am very much confused why it's not getting a form and other tags in bootstrap. After going through error i also identified that react conmvert the bootstrap.Form into _reactbootstrap2.Default.Form. and default is appearing as undefined. while debugging. but _reactbootstrap2 contains the Form as a element.
No clue whats going on.

I have installed react-bootstrap using below command 
`npm install --save react-bootstrap` in my project directory path

Answer (score 1):

`react-bootstrap` does not have a default export.

Instead of `import Bootstrap from "react-bootstrap"`, try:

```
import { Form, Col, FormGroup, Checkbox } from 'react-bootstrap' // add more if you are using more components from bootstrap
```

Then just use `<Form>` instead of `<Bootstrap.Form>`.

Comment: I updated the code and also changed LoginForm.ControlLabel to ControlLabel. its showing error as index.js:40729 Uncaught ReferenceError: ControlLabel is not defined . do i have to add ControlLabel too

Comment: Did you add `ControlLabel` to the list of imports above?

Comment: yes after adding it started working.. But now issue is css is not getting applied  to textbox .in inspect element it's showing all css classes are applied to component it in UI it's missing. Do i have to install any other package for it?